# Issue with Django login and profile View

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-views, django-authentication

I am new to Django and tried existing answers but did not work for me. I would appreciate your help!

I have two logins, 1 with Facebook and 1 with Django. 
I have this profile view on my page. If you login with Facebook you can access your profile page and make changes. But if you login without a Facebook account (regular user object) you get redirected to the home page where it should be redirected to the profile page.

In the Django admin user page, all users are listed. But on the user profile page, it's showing only social auth users from Facebook. What can I do to resolve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
    @login_required(login_url="/")
    def profile(request, username):
      if request.method == 'POST':
         profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
         profile.about = request.POST['about']
         profile.slogan = request.POST['slogan']
         profile.skill = request.POST['skill']
         profile.save()
     else:
         try:

            profile = Profile.objects.get(user__username=username)
            return render(request,'profile.html',{'user':user})

         except Profile.DoesNotExist:
             return redirect('/')
```

models.py view

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500)
about = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
slogan = models.CharField(max_length=500)
skill = models.CharField(max_length=500, null='True')

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Comment: Please share Model code also social auth code how you process after successful social login.

Comment: thanks for consideration. I added

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user__username=username)
```

to

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

as `username` is undeclared.

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to help. This is not working. Any more ideas?